# Fixed Navbar & Body Scrolling broken on IOS

Tags: javascript, woocommerce, navbar

On mobile, when clicking the button to open the navbar we have written javascript to lock the body and allow the navbar to scroll **(see code below)**, this works perfectly on android. However, when testing this on iPhones it is completely broken. Sometimes it completely stops scrolling on the navbar, sometimes doesn't open the navbar and stops the scrolling on the body instead. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**[Our Website](http://s2br5s5r3.gb-02.live-paas.net)**

```
//In Global JavaScript
jQuery( function($) { 

$( ".x-btn-navbar" ).on( "touchstart", function() {
  $('body').toggleClass("fixedPosition");
});
});

//In Global CSS
.fixedPosition{
position: fixed;
}
```

Comment: can you try `.on('click')` instead of `touchstart`

Comment: @AravindS That is what we originally had and it wasn't working on IOS either

Comment: can you change the CSS to `height: 100%; overflow: hidden` for both `body and html` and try?